# How to make a class that collects static data?

Tags: java, collections, singleton

Let's say that we have a `Condition` class.

```
public abstract class Condition<T>
{
    private List<T> _list = new ArrayList<>();

    // add, remove, get methods
}
```

If we make another class that extends the `Condition` class, how can I keep the objects stored if I make a new instance of that class?

For example:

```
SampleCondition c1 = new SampleCondition();
c1.addItem("text");

SampleCondition c2 = new SampleCondition();
c2.addItem("more text");
```

Those two classes won't contain both "text" and "more text". The only possible way I could think of is to make the class a singleton, however that's not the best practice, any suggestions are much appreciated.

Edit: If I make the `_list` field static, would another class extending the Condition class share the stored objects in SampleCondition class?

Comment: What goal you a really trying to achieve? What is a business-level purpose of your classes?

Comment: In respond to @VladimirSerykh: you may have a [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: I am trying to store objects in a certain condition, such as a player spectating or frozen.

Comment: And why do you need to have the same condition-list every time you call the constuctor? Would it not be better to give each object a condition-list?

Comment: So each class has it's own field?

Comment: @Thanos this would be one possibility, yes.

Comment: I see your point, if I do that, what would be an efficient way to not copy-paste handful methods used in modifying the list? An interface or an abstract that requires the list itself in the constructor?

Comment: All things aside, perhaps you want to make a factory? Have your list be on the factory floor, and then every time you need a new condition, have the factory build it with a link to the (single and only) list, and return it to the user.